# Show keyboard when TextView is clicked on Mono for Android

Tags: android, keyboard, textview, xamarin.android

How can I get the keyboard to show, when someone clicks on a TextView field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this on textview click

```
InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(yourActivity.this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(InputMethodService);
    imm.ToggleSoftInput(ShowSoftInputFlags.Forced,HideSoftInputFlags.None );
}
```